# unable to retrieve images from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a problem when I want to display text and images from Firebase, the text can come out while the image can't be displayed.

this is my model class :

```
public class Model {
    String title, image, description;

    //constructor
    public Model(){}

    //getter and setters press Alt+Insert

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

this is my view holder class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }



        public void setDetails (Context ctx, String title, String description, String image){
            //Views
            TextView mTitleTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
            TextView mDetailTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
            ImageView mImageIv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
            //set data to views
            mTitleTv.setText(title);
            mDetailTv.setText(description);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageIv);
        }


    }
```

and this is my main activity

```
package com.ainuralizar.firebaseproject;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class PostListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list);



        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("post list");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class,R.layout.row , ViewHolder.class ,mRef) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getTitle(),model.getDescription(),model.getImage());
                    }
                };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

I have tried to change my data but it's still unable to display the images stored in firebase. I hope there you guys have a solution for it, sorry for bad English

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukJXt.png)

Comment: Did you debug the app what you are getting image refrence? The image you have defined here   Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageIv);

Comment: show an image of your database, not in a link. Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The image URL you are using is not valid URL, image URL should start with `https://` or `http://` e.g.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukJXt.png

or

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukJXt.png

Do verify image URL with the browser you will be able to view the image if the URL is valid.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is there any other alternative where I just enter the link without https from storage?

Comment: But why you want to store image URL without https or http

Comment: oh, you're right, I just read the documentation, I think I can retrieve data without https. thank you for the help sir

Comment: @AINNU you can also decide not to store imageUrl , i you know what is the name of image, i my app i name to image same as the reference key of the person node for which the image is, at runtime i query storage with that name and get the url of it, it is help in case the url is revoked, note that if you revoke the url , it object will still  contain old one